# app doesn't work when open the app level build gradle

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

when i open the app level build gradle file, the whole app doesn't work and give me this message

Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] Error launching the application on Android SDK built for x86.

Answer (score 1):

It means you don't have sufficient storage... Flutter will take some temporary storage whenever its in use to load everything in. Please check your storage when this problem comes up. I have seen it take 5 6 GBs or more for running apps sometimes. It offloads those files as soon as you close your editor.

Comment: Just try to see what's up with your storage whenever you try to run or use Flutter

Answer (score 1):

Wipe All the data of emulator like this:
[image]

Because emulator have limited space to use.If you want to give more memory you can change internal space option in settings.
[image]